# Modal Formbuilder for wagtail?

Tags: django, wagtail

Hello im new to wagtail and its been really awesome so far. However im facing an issue trying to create a modal version of the formbuilder. My intentions is to create an action button within the base.html of which the user can click at any point in time and enter a modal pop up form to leave a feed back . Is there a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very doable, you will need to work out how you want your modals to look and work by finding a suitable modal library.

Once you have that, you will need to determine how your admin interface will provide the setting of which `FormPage` will be used on the base template to render the modal. Wagtail's [site settings](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html) is a good option.

From here, you then need to get the linked form and use it's `get_form()` method (all pages that extend `AbstractForm` or `AbstractEmailForm` have this). If you want to understand how the form is processed you can see the code [here](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/contrib/forms/models.py#L123).

The simplest way to handle form submissions is to POST to the original form, this way there does not need to be any additional handling elsewhere. You also get the 'success' page as per normal without having to render that inside the modal.

Below is a basic code example that should get you started.

### Example Code Walk-through

#### 1. install wagtail settings

- This will enable us to have some site wide settings to configure which form will be used in the modal
- Docs - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html#site-settings

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS += [
    'wagtail.contrib.settings',
]
```

#### 2. Set up a settings model

- This will contain a relationship to any `FormPage`, you will need to create the [form page](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/forms/index.html) separately.
- Note: you may want to uncheck 'show in menus' on the form page, unless you want users to be able to go to that form on its own URL also
- Docs - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html#defining-settings
- Remember to run `makemigrations` & `migrate`

```py
from django.db import models
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers PageChooserPanel

# ... other models & imports

@register_setting
class MyAppSettings(BaseSetting):
    # relationship to a single form page (one per site)
    modal_form_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name='Modal Form'
    )

    panels = [
        # note the kwarg - this will only allow form pages to be selected (replace base with your app)
        PageChooserPanel('modal_form_page', page_type='base.FormPage')
    ]
```

#### 3. Install a basic modal library

- This will be up to you, if you use bootsrap for example it comes with a modal library
- For this example I have used https://micromodal.now.sh/#installation
- There are lots of ways to do this, this is the simplest and does not require any async background calls to the server

3a. Add the css in your static folder (e.g. my-app/static/css/micromodal.css) & then import it in your central header or layout template.

```html
<head>
  <!-- ALL OTHER ITEMS -->
  <!-- Modal CSS -->
  <link href="{% static 'css/micromodal.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
```

3b. Add the JS & init call in your base template, best to do this as the last item before the closing `body` tag

```html
<!-- Modal JS -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/micromodal/dist/micromodal.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        MicroModal.init();
    });
</script>
```

#### 4. Set up a template tag

- There are a few ways to do this, but basically we want our `base.html` template to have a convenient way to place the modal & modal trigger. Django's `template tags` are a great way to do this.
- Docs - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags
- Using the instructions in the Wagtail site settings page we can import our settings model and access the related form page, from here we can generate the form object.
- The template code below is the bare minimum, you will want to do more styling probably, it assumes the trigger will just be rendered along with the modal content.
- The template contains some basic logic to allow for tracking of the page the form was submitted on `source-page-id` so we can redirect the user to their source page and request.session reading to show a success message.

```py
# my-app/templatetags/modal_tags.py
from django import template
from models import MyAppSettings

register = template.Library()

# reminder - you will need to restart Django when adding a template tag


@register.inclusion_tag('tags/form_modal.html', takes_context=True)
def form_modal(context):
    request = context['request']  # important - you must have the request in context
    settings = MyAppSettings.for_request(request)
    form_page = settings.modal_form_page

    if not form_page:
        return context

    form_page = form_page.specific

    # this will provide the parts needed to render the form
    # this does NOT handle the submission of the form - that still goes to the form page
    # this does NOT handle anything to do with rendering the 'thank you' message

    context['form_page'] = form_page
    context['form'] = form_page.get_form(page=form_page, user=request.user)

    return context
```

```html
{% comment %} e.g. my-app/templates/tags/form_modal.html {% endcomment %}
{% load wagtailcore_tags %}

{% if request.session.form_page_success %}
  Thanks for submitting the form!
{% endif %}

{% if form %}

<button data-micromodal-trigger="modal-1">Open {{ form_page.title }} Modal</button>

<div class="modal micromodal-slide" id="modal-1" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal__overlay" tabindex="-1" data-micromodal-close>
    <div class="modal__container" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-1-title">
      <header class="modal__header">
        <h2 class="modal__title" id="modal-1-title">
          {{ form_page.title }}
        </h2>
        <button class="modal__close" aria-label="Close modal" data-micromodal-close></button>
      </header>
      <form action="{% pageurl form_page %}" method="POST" role="form">
        <main class="modal__content" id="modal-1-content">
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          {% if page.pk != form_page.pk %}
          {% comment %} only provide the source page if not on the actual form page {% endcomment %}
          <input name="source-page-id" type="hidden" value="{{ page.pk }}">
          {% endif %}
        </main>
        <footer class="modal__footer">
          <input class="modal__btn modal__btn-primary" type="submit">
          <button class="modal__btn" data-micromodal-close aria-label="Close this dialog window">Close</button>
        </footer>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% endif %}
```

#### 5. Use the template tag where you want the modal trigger

- Now you can add the modal (along with its trigger)
- Important: for the template tag above to have access to the request via context, you may need to add this (depending on your setup).

```html
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        {% form_modal %}
        {% include "includes/footer.html" %}
    </footer>
```

#### 6. Redirecting back to the source page

- As a final step we can redirect the user back to their source page by reading the `source-page-id` from the `request.POST`.
- From this ID we can get the original URL and use Django's [`redirect` shortcut](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect).
- Before we redirect, we updated `request.session` with some data so we can show a success message.
- This can be done by overriding the `render_landing_page` on your `FormPage`
- Docs - https://docs.wagtail.io/en/latest/reference/contrib/forms/customisation.html#custom-landing-page-redirect

```py
# models.py

class FormPage(AbstractEmailForm):
    # .. fields etc

    def render_landing_page(self, request, form_submission=None, *args, **kwargs):
        source_page_id = request.POST.get('source-page-id')
        source_page = Page.objects.get(pk=source_page_id)

        if source_page:
            request.session['form_page_success'] = True
            return redirect(source_page.url, permanent=False)

        # if no source_page is set, render default landing page
        return super().render_landing_page(request, form_submission, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey there , thank you so much for such a detailed answer , i got it to work for me somehow haha. If i may , there's one thing that i couldn't resolve. Is it possible to override the landing page? As in i dont wish to have a landing page , i just want the data to be submitted with a success message on the top of the screen(redirects back to where i was)

Comment: Hi @neowenshun - I have updated the answer with a few fixes and a step 6 which covers a custom redirect 'back' to the source page. This is still really only a starting point but hopefully helps.

Comment: hi , thank you so much for your comments , im almost getting it all to come together thanks to you. However im stuck at a particular problem , may i know where you got the source-page-id from ? it returns none type object for me

Comment: If you have a look at the updated answer, it is in the `input type="hidden"` as part of the form_modal.html tag